# How to run wiremock-in-a-docker-container and still get the failsafe test report?

Tags: java, maven, docker, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

**TLDR:** The solution I am currently trying to implement is to have 3 docker containers: DB, SUT and INTEGRATION_TESTS. The problem is that within the container I can not use the maven-failsafe-plugin and that means - no test reports.

**Full story:**

I am trying to get a test report from my integration tests which are run within a docker container.

Until recently we had a setup of test DB running in one docker container, SUT running in another and and maven-failsafe-plugin running the integration tests in host system.

Now, however, the integration tests use the wiremock and provide a TCP port to which the SUT must connect. Due to tests being run sometimes on Bamboo build server and sometimes on developer machines (linuxes and macs) the old setup is no longer feasible (on macs for example, the host could be reached only through "docker.for.mac.localhost" DNS name which is unavailable on Bamboo).

I see the following possible solutions, but every seems to have its downsides:

- do not generate test reports (no reports sucks)
- generate test reports manually (custom code)
- run a dedicated container for wiremocks and run tests outside (one more container, incomplete dockerization)

The last option seems like the best one, but may be there is a way I can trigger the failsafe report generation code from the command line (i.e. "java -jar ......")?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that plugin, but can you clarify (if only my own education!) why it doesn't work from inside a container?

Comment: It requires maven to run and I was resistent to copying the source code into the container. I have since learned that you can share a part of your file system with docker which makes the solution more attractive.

In the meantime the decision was to go with the "dedicated wiremock container" and it seems to work.